# How to use NumPy arrays while Plotting Live Data in Real-Time?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation, plot

How to use numpy arrays correctly during live construction plot, I mean if I use these arrays i push values into and everything is good with the exception of line which starts from (0;0) and points each time on current plot's point, in other words first end stays stable, but second changes it location. What to do with this? Also I don't understand how to pass parameters by reference at animation().

```
s = '.........................................................................................'+
string.ascii_uppercase
letters = [s[randint(0, len(s)-1)] for _ in range(5000)] #массив букв
time    = [i for i in range(5000)]
example = [randint(0, 100) for _ in range(5000)]

t = count()
frequency = 0
time_x = np.zeros(len(time))
key_y = np.zeros(len(time))

cnt = 0

def animate(i):
    global cnt
    time_x[cnt] = time[cnt]
    key_y[cnt] = example[cnt]

    print (time_x[cnt], key_y[cnt])
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(time_x, key_y)
    cnt += 1

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=3000)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line where you do `plt.plot(time_x, key_y)`, because `time_x` and `key_y` are instantiated as an array of zeros, there was always lines being drawn from your last generated point to a [0, 0] location (until you generate the points where `cnt=4999`).

e.g. If `cnt=2` in your data generation loop, it might look like:

```
time_x = [  0.0, 1.0,  2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...]
key_y  = [100.0, 1.0, 52.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...]
```

which means you're also plotting a lot of zeros!

I think you only wanted to plot up to `cnt` (for which you had generated data), i.e. `plt.plot(time_x[:cnt], key_y[:cnt])`, or in your example:

```py
import numpy as np
from random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

s = '.........................................................................................'
letters = [s[randint(0, len(s)-1)] for _ in range(5000)]
time = [i for i in range(5000)]
example = [randint(0, 100) for _ in range(5000)]

time_x = np.zeros(len(time))
key_y = np.zeros(len(time))

def animate(cnt, param_1, param_2):
    time_x[cnt] = time[cnt]
    key_y[cnt] = example[cnt]
    print(cnt, time_x[cnt], key_y[cnt], f'Extra params: {param_1}, {param_2}')
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(time_x[:cnt], key_y[:cnt])


extra_params = ('p_1', 'p_2')

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=3000, fargs=extra_params)
plt.show()
```

The first parameter passed to animate (`i`) is already what the `global` `cnt`
used to do in your original code, so you can just replace it. If you want to pass in specific `cnt` values, as suggested [in the docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation), you can try adding a `frames` argument.

If you want to pass in other parameters, you can use the `fargs` argument. You can pass in extra data as a tuple, as shown by `extra_params`.

In the event you want to do something more complicated, I would use a python class to store the state instead, as shown in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511843/python-animation-without-globals).

Comment: Thank you, it helped. It is possible to pass cnt into animation() by link?

Comment: @MrFilonxik I've edited my answer, let me know if you meant something else!